# "new" modifier causes base implementations to have NULL property values

Tags: c#, .net, polymorphism, derived-class

I'm trying to use Polymorphism to have a derived class operate with a derived property instead of the base property.  I'm not sure how to put it in clearer words, so here's an example with the output:

```
// setup output to demonstrate the scenario
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var foo = new Foo();            
    var foobase = foo as FooBase;

    Console.WriteLine("Foo is null? {0}", foo == null);
    Console.WriteLine("Foo.Bar is null? {0}", foo.Bar == null);
    Console.WriteLine("FooBase is null? {0}", foobase == null);
    Console.WriteLine("FooBase.Bar is null? {0}", foobase.Bar == null);
    Console.ReadLine();            
}

// base and derived.  These represent my problem.
class BarBase { }
class Bar : BarBase { }

// Base implementation using base properties
class FooBase
{
    public virtual BarBase Bar { get; set; }
    public FooBase() { }
}

// Derived implementation using "new" to operate with the 
// derived the property
class Foo : FooBase
{
    public new Bar Bar { get; set; }
    public Foo() : base()
    {
        // populate our modified property with the derived class
        Bar = new Bar();
        //base.Bar = Bar; // I don't want to do this, but how can I avoid it?
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Foo is null? False
Foo.Bar is null? False
FooBase is null? False
FooBase.Bar is null? True
```

The problem is "FooBase.Bar" is NULL.  I understand that the *new* modifier is hiding the base implementation, that's why I know I can make it work by adding the (commented out) line:

```
base.Bar = Bar; // I don't want to do this, but how can I avoid it?
```

Is there a better way?  What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

---

**EDIT** (6/7/11)

Adding a more specific example to my problem.  Basically, there are abstract implementations for a Game and a Camera (very basic here...).  The abstract Game uses the abstract Camera for basic work.  The derived Game uses its derived Camera for its specialty work.  In the end, I'd need both the derived and the abstract Cameras to work in their own scope.

I've given two different Camera implementations and two Game implementations to (hopefully) demonstrate the flexibility I'm looking for. Please note that Game1 uses a "hack" to force the base Camera to have a value- Game2 does not do this.  Game1 has the *behavior* I want, but not the *implementation* I want.

```
class GameAndCameraExample
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Game1().Play();
        Console.WriteLine();
        new Game2().Play();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    // abstract camera
    abstract class CameraBase
    {
        public void SpecialCameraBaseMethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SpecialCameraBaseMethod");
        }
    }

    // camera implementation
    class ChaseCamera : CameraBase
    {
        public void SpecialChaseCameraMethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SpecialChaseCameraMethod");
        }
    }

    // a different camera implementation
    class FlightCamera : CameraBase
    {
        public void SpecialFlightCameraMethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SpecialFlightCameraMethod");
        }
    }

    // abstract game
    abstract class GameBase
    {
        public virtual CameraBase Camera { get; set; }

        public GameBase() { }

        public virtual void Play()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("GameBase.Camera is null? {0}", Camera == null);
            if(Camera != null) // it will be null for Game2 :-(
                Camera.SpecialCameraBaseMethod(); 
        }
    }

    // awesome game using chase cameras
    class Game1 : GameBase
    {
        public new ChaseCamera Camera { get; set; }

        public Game1() : base()
        {
            Camera = new ChaseCamera();
            base.Camera = Camera; // HACK: How can I avoid this?
        }

        public override void Play()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Game.Camera is null? {0}", Camera == null);
            Camera.SpecialChaseCameraMethod();
            base.Play();
        }
    }

    // even more awesome game using flight cameras
    class Game2 : GameBase
    {
        public new FlightCamera Camera { get; set; }
        public Game2()
            : base()
        {
            Camera = new FlightCamera();
        }

        public override void Play()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Game.Camera is null? {0}", Camera == null);
            Camera.SpecialFlightCameraMethod();
            base.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Game.Camera is null? False
SpecialChaseCameraMethod
GameBase.Camera is null? False
SpecialCameraBaseMethod

Game.Camera is null? False
SpecialFlightCameraMethod
GameBase.Camera is null? True
```

Is inheritance even the best approach for this?

Comment: Added a new example to better reflect my actual problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to present an answer to my own question.  Actually, two answers.  There are likely many other answers but none are finding their way here.

**Solution #1: Parallel Hierarchies**

This idea was brought up by @Joel B Fant in an earlier comment.  I looked over how ADO.NET is implemented (via Reflector) to come up with an implementation.  I'm not thrilled about this pattern because it means multiple properties for the same *family* of objects- but it is a reasonable solution.

*(Let's assume that the CameraBase, FlightCamera, and ChaseCamera from my question are still defined to save space)*

**CODE**

```
// abstract game
abstract class GameBase
{
    public virtual CameraBase CameraBase { get; set; }
    public GameBase() { }
    public virtual void Play()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("GameBase.CameraBase is null? {0}", CameraBase == null);
        if (CameraBase != null)
            CameraBase.SpecialCameraBaseMethod();
    }
}

// awesome game using chase cameras
class Game1 : GameBase
{
    public override CameraBase CameraBase 
    { 
        get { return Camera; } 
        set { Camera = (ChaseCamera)value; } 
    }
    public ChaseCamera Camera { get; set; }
    public Game1()
    {
        Camera = new ChaseCamera();
    }
    public override void Play()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Game.Camera is null? {0}", Camera == null);
        Camera.SpecialChaseCameraMethod();
        base.Play();
    }
}
```

**Solution #2: Inheritance, Injection, and a Twist**

This "pattern" might have a real name, but I don't know it. It's very similar to Parallel Hierarchies (as well as my original example) except I'm injecting the camera through the constructor and using the base properties (with casting) for access.  I suppose I could have avoided the injection and do a straight assignment to the base property as well (but why avoid injection? It's so useful!).  The *twist* is simply the required casting for the properties.  It's not clean, but it's not ugly either.  This is my current preferred solution.

**CODE**

```
// must inject the camera for this solution
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    new Game1(new ChaseCamera()).Play();
    Console.ReadLine();
}

// abstract game
abstract class GameBase
{
    public virtual CameraBase Camera { get; set; }
    public GameBase(CameraBase camera) // injection
    {
        Camera = camera;
    }
    public virtual void Play()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("GameBase.Camera is null? {0}", Camera == null);
        if (Camera != null)
            Camera.SpecialCameraBaseMethod();
    }
}

// awesome game using chase cameras
class Game1 : GameBase
{
    public new ChaseCamera Camera 
    { 
        get { return (ChaseCamera)base.Camera; } 
        set { base.Camera = value; } 
    }
    public Game1(ChaseCamera camera) : base(camera) { } // injection
    public override void Play()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Game.Camera is null? {0}", Camera == null);
        Camera.SpecialChaseCameraMethod();
        base.Play();
    }
}
```

Both of these solutions give me the desired results with an acceptable implementation.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `override` instead of `new`.

You can still return a `Bar` object, thought it will still return as `BarBase`. But `override` is the only way to make sure that `Foo`'s property is used instead of `FooBase`'s property when the `Foo` object is cast as `FooBase`.

Generics could help in this situation, mainly on the `FooBase` class:

```
class FooBase<T> where T: BarBase {
    public virtual T Bar { get; set; }
    public FooBase() { }
}

class Foo : FooBase<Bar> {
    public override Bar Bar { get; set; }
    public Foo() : base() {
        Bar = new Bar();
    }
}
```

And here's the modifications to `Main()`:

```
static void Main( string[] args ) {
    var foo = new Foo();
    var foobase = foo as FooBase<Bar>;

    Console.WriteLine( "Foo is null? {0}", foo == null );
    Console.WriteLine( "Foo.Bar is null? {0}", foo.Bar == null );
    Console.WriteLine( "FooBase is null? {0}", foobase == null );
    Console.WriteLine( "FooBase.Bar is null? {0}", foobase.Bar == null );
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

The constraint of generic parameter `T` to `BarBase` means any subclass of `FooBase` can opt-in to any subclass of `BarBase`, or just deal with `BarBase`:

```
class VagueFoo : FooBase<BarBase> { }
```

Comment: Thanks, but override requires the members to match. "'Foo.Bar': type must be 'BarBase' to match overridden member 'FooBase.Bar'"

Comment: Right, I'm seeing if I can redesign a bit to see if generic parameters can help you.

Comment: Although this solution works (and thanks!), it will get pretty ugly once you have multiple properties that need the same behavior- especially if _foo_ is a fairly common Type being used. It might be that I need to consider a different approach to my architecture. I'll leave it open a bit to see if any other solutions are offered.

Comment: I guess that depends on your class hierarchies. How simplified and far off from your real class hierarchy is the foo/bar example? Is it more like the derived classes based on the ADO.NET classes? (`OdbcCommand` and `SqlClientCommand` based on `DbCommand`, etc.: parallel hierarchies)

Comment: This example was simplified to demonstrate my problem.  My actual class hierarchy could have many similar scenarios.  I'm going to consider other techniques (like composition) instead of inheritance.  Your ADO.NET example might be a good comparison for what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Foo : FooBase
{
    public override BarBase Bar { get; set; }
    public Foo() : base()
    {
        // populate our modified property with the derived class
        Bar = new Bar();
        //base.Bar = Bar; // I don't want to do this, but how can I avoid it?
    }
}
```

You may try this: change Property type to BarBase and use override. Then use polimorphism to assign a derived class Bar object to the BarBase Property. Property Bar is virtual so the right object will be returned.

Comment: Correct. Unfortunately this means any consumers of _Foo_ will need to cast the result of _Bar_ in order to access methods/properties defined in _Bar_ but not in _BarBase_. This is exactly what I'm hoping to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Heres a tip for solution:

```
class GameAndCameraExample
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Game1().Play();
        Console.WriteLine();
        new Game2().Play();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }    

    // abstract camera  
    abstract class CameraBase
    {
        public void SpecialCameraBaseMethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SpecialCameraBaseMethod");
        }
    }    

    // camera implementation    
    class ChaseCamera : CameraBase
    {
        public void SpecialChaseCameraMethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SpecialChaseCameraMethod");
        }
    }    

    // a different camera implementation   
    class FlightCamera : CameraBase
    {
        public void SpecialFlightCameraMethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SpecialFlightCameraMethod");
        }
    }    

    // abstract game   
    abstract class GameBase<T> where T : CameraBase, new()
    {
        public T Camera { get; set; }

        public GameBase()
        {
            Camera = new T();
        }

        public virtual void Play()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("GameBase.Camera is null? {0}", Camera == null); 
            if (Camera != null) // it will be null for Game2 :-(              
                Camera.SpecialCameraBaseMethod();
        }
    }   

    // awesome game using chase cameras  
    class Game1 : GameBase<ChaseCamera>
    {
        public override void Play()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Game.Camera is null? {0}", Camera == null); 
            Camera.SpecialChaseCameraMethod(); 
            base.Play();
        }
    }

    // even more awesome game using flight cameras    
    class Game2 : GameBase<FlightCamera>
    {
        public override void Play()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Game.Camera is null? {0}", Camera == null); 
            Camera.SpecialFlightCameraMethod(); 
            base.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope you find this useful.
-Zsolt