# c# asp mvc how to get derived class object values

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ienumerable, idictionary

Can anyone help how to get derived class objects values?

When I try to cast from derived class (Currency) to parent class (Entity) I get null's.
Real values from DB: http://prntscr.com/ahmy9h
Null's after casting to Entity: http://prntscr.com/ahmxxo

```
public class Entity
{
    public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Currency:Entity
{
    public Currency()
    {
        this.BankServices = new HashSet<BankService>();
    }

    public new System.Guid Id { get; set; }
    public new string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<BankService> BankServices { get; set; }
}

public virtual IEnumerable<Entity> GetItems()
{
    // check the cache
    Dictionary<Guid, Entity> EntityData = GetCachedData();

    // If it's not in the cache, read it from the repository
    if (EntityData == null)
    {
        // Get the data
        Dictionary<Guid, Entity> EntityDataToCache = new Dictionary<Guid, Entity>();

        // get data from the repository
        IEnumerable<Entity> entityDataFromDb = LoadData();
        foreach (var item in entityDataFromDb)
        {
            var itemValue = item; // ALL ZEROS http://prntscr.com/ahmxxo
            var itemValue2 = (Currency)item; // REAL VALUES http://prntscr.com/ahmy9h
            EntityDataToCache[(Guid)item.GetType().GetProperty("Id").GetValue(item, null)] = item;
        }

        if (EntityDataToCache.Any())
        {
            // Put this data into the cache for 30 minutes
            Cache.Set(CacheKey, EntityDataToCache, 30);
        }
    }

    var cache = Cache.Get(CacheKey);

    var result = cache as Dictionary<Guid, Entity>;
    return result.Values;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["new" modifier causes base implementations to have NULL property values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239790/new-modifier-causes-base-implementations-to-have-null-property-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest reading [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or something similar to brush up on the difference between inheritance and hiding.  In your case, the `new` modifier on the `Currency.Id` and `Currency.Name` properties tells the compiler to hide those properties in the parent class.  So, when you assign those properties in a `Currency` instance, those values are only applicable to that instance as an instance of `Currency`.  As you've seen from your code, if you cast that instance to an instance of `Entity`, references to those properties are references to the `Entity` properties (which you haven't set).  In order to get the behavior I think you're looking for, you'll want to add the `virtual` modifier to the property declarations in `Entity`, then change `new` to `override` in `Currency`.  Of course, if you're not changing the behavior of these properties between `Currency` and `Entity` then you don't need to override them in `Currency` at all...they'll be available to all classes that inherit from `Entity`.  Hope that helps.